# Как получить обратную связь одного объекта к другому в моделях Django

Tags: django, django-admin

Есть две модели из разных приложений, типа:

model1.py

```
class SomeClass1(models.Model):

  short_name = models.CharField(...)
  compatibility = models.ManyToManyField(SomeClass2, ....)
```

model2.py

```
class SomeClass2(models.Model):

  name_dev = models.CharField(...)
```

Собственно, когда я создаю объект **model1** , то могу выбрать связанные объекты из **model2**.  И в шаблоне я могу обратится типа - `{{object.compatibility.name_dev}}`

Но также в шаблоне я бы хотел получить все объекты которые сослались на связанный объект из **model2**

Возможно, что то типа такого:

views2.py

```
object2 = SomeClass2.objects.all()
```

В шаблоне:

`{% for object in object2 %}`

```
`{{object.(...)compatibility.short_name}}`
```

`{% endfor %}`

Можно добавить поле во вторую модель, но это придется опять вручную выбирать объекты из **model1**. Этого и хотелось бы избежать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django автоматически добавляет *поля*  для manytomany.

В Вашем случае автоматически доступны такие фильтры:

```
SomeClass1.objects.filter(someclass2__name_dev = u'Sidorov')
```

Comment: В общем-то да. Только я немного изменил конструкцию и стало то что  надо:
`SomeClass1.objects.filter(compatibility__name_dev = u'Sidorov')`

Ваш вариант выводил пару каких то, для меня непонятных, объекта.

**Спасибо**

Comment: Выводит объекты соответствующие SomeClass1, на которые есть ссылка по фильтру name_dev в SomeClass1. А вообще там очень много всяких доступных. Пользуюсь pycharm, в нем есть autocomplete - предлагает кучу ключей для ManyToMany. Если ответ помог - поставьте как решение :)